# htaccess rewrite rules to hide joomla in subdirectory conflicting with multiple domain names

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, joomla3.0

Here's my situation. I have a Joomla 3.3.6 install sitting in a subdirectory, which I'll call `joomla`. It needs to stay in that subdirectory and I need it to be accessed through urls like `mysite.com/en/mypage` instead of `mysite.com/joomla/en/mypage`. I have other services living on the same host that need to remain accessible, all in other subdirectories.

I also have three domain names for the same server (as "parked domains" hosted by a webhost that uses cpanel, not something I can change), say `mysiteA.com`, `mysiteB.com` and `mysiteC.com` - they should all point to the same Joomla install transparently, i.e. `mysiteA.com/en/mypage = mysiteB.com/en/mypage`.

Now I successfully redirected all requests to the joomla subdirectory, effectively hiding it, with a combination of

**.htaccess** (inspired by [this blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2009/01/31/how-to-get-your-joomla-in-a-sub-directory-to-work-at-onecom/)))

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

#Do a permanent redirect from something.tld to www.something.tld (yes-www)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Hide the joomla subdirectory joomla
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/joomla/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ joomla/index.php [L]
```

and

**joomla/configuration.php**

```
(...)
public $live_site = 'http://www.mysiteA.com';
(...)
```

Now here's the thing. The site works well whenever accessed through `mysiteA.com` only: `http://www.mysiteA.com/en/mypage` does what it's supposed to, but `http://www.mysiteB.com/en/mypage` returns a 404. This is probably due to the `$live_site` variable being set as above. However, if I let that variable empty, or set it to `/`, the subdirectory is not hidden anymore, i.e. `http://www.mysiteB.com/en/mypage` always redirects to `http://www.mysiteB.com/joomla/en/mypage`

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to achieve what I want without virtual hosts (which I don't think my webhost allow me to)? I guess always redirecting `mysiteB` and `mysiteC` to `mysiteA` in .htaccess would kind of solve my problem, but I would lose the transparency that I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the VirtualHost configuration file for `mysiteA.com`

Comment: Mmh, I'm not sure how to do this. My webhost only lets me administer the site via cpanel. I don't think I have access to this file but I'll ask.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can set up an Apache redirect from http to https, you will need to do the following:

- Make sure your SSL certificate is successfully installed so you can
  access https:// www. yoursite.com
- Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache

Now you just need to edit your httpd.conf file or the file where your virtual host is specified and add these lines to redirect http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

In many cases, you can also just add those lines to a file named .htaccess in the folder that you want to redirect http to https.

Now, when a visitor types http: //www.yoursite.com/mypage.htm the server will automatically redirect http to https so that they go to https: //www.yoursite.com/mypage.htm

Note: You can also redirect a single page from http to http in Apache by using this in your configuration file or .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^apache-redirect-http-to-https\.html$ https://www.yoursite.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html [R=301,L]
```